# Adaptive card for overall rating

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

How to create Adaptive card for Overall Rating similar to Skype Post call survey:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a good place to start is probably [adaptivecards.io](http://adaptivecards.io/).  There you can familiarize yourself with the schema and even look at [examples](http://adaptivecards.io/samples/).  there's also an area you can play with the schema to make the card look how you need.  some other useful links:

[Getting started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots)

[Adaptive cards repo(has samples)](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards)

[Simple walkthrough](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/07/adaptive-card-dotnet/)

Comment: All examples are in c#, is exist any way to use json created in http://adaptivecards.io/?

Comment: yes adaptive cards have a JSON schema.  Take a look at the visualizer in adaptivecards.io

Comment: Ok, but how I can use them (in json format) within ms bot Framework?